# Error starting a test with testacular

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying out the angularjs tutorials on a 64 bit Windows 7 system because I find this framework quite interesting from what I read on its home page. I am a newbie to node.js and not experienced in Java-Script.

When running the tests, I get the following error. Can anybody find out what the problem is or give some hints how to determine that? I have a fresh Installation of node and added testacular with

> npm install -g testacular

which worked fine from what was printed on the console window.

So here is the error message:

> PS C:\Users\xx\Documents\Angular\angular-phonecat> .\scripts\test.bat
>   INFO [testacular]: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
>   INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
>   ERROR [testacular]: { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
>   Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:948:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:739:34)

Comment: Well, do you have `chrome` installed and in your path? The error is basically telling you that `child_process.spawn` threw `ENOENT` which usually means that the executable couldn't be found

Comment: Yep, Chrome is installed and I've added Chrome's application Folder to the PATH variable. Is there a way to find out what process node.js was trying to start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer:
**Set env variable CHROME_BIN to full path to chrome.exe**

The error msg is confusing, as the behavior of spawn got changed in Node 0.10, we need to update it (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/452)

Comment: Btw, the project has been renamed to Karma, so you might rather install `npm install karma`, as Testacular package won't be updated on NPM.

Comment: If you are running on Windows make sure you don't put quotes around the path even if there are spaces in it, just the full path to the exe like `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`.

Comment: @clav thanks for pointing that out, btw. with the latest Karma this is not an issue, as Karma checks for the quotes first and remove them if you use them...

Answer (score 0):

Inserting 'PhantomJS' for the test browser in the karma configuration file on Windows Vista resulted in the same error message:  { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }

I ad-libbed on the advice above and inserted in the system path ("Environmental Variables") under "User variables for owner" PHANTOMJS_BIN with the value consisting of the path including phantomjs.exe (C:\Program Files\phantomjs-1.9.0-windows\phantomjs.exe)

All good, jasmine angularjs tests running now and much faster than with 'Chrome' or 'Firefox' as the test browser.